# push notification apps using wysiwyg app builders

Tags: android, iphone

this is rather a generic question and I'm not sure where to put it.

Just wondering if there are any good app builders which offer user subscription as a feature and if it is possible to send push notifications to certain unique users. For example, if I have 10 users who have downloaded my app (numbered 1 to 10), would it be possible for them all to log in and would it be possible for me to send push notifications to only User 1,3 and 5?
Also, is there any way they can respond to this notification via my app?

Any info about an app builder with such features would be appreciated. I've checked a few such as AppMakr, but they don't seem to offer such functionality/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try GCM (Google Cloud Messeging)Please check the below link to start with.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html